# Remove country code from url in Nginx with regex

Tags: regex, nginx, server

I need to configure the replacement of the url containing the country code. Example:

```
example.ru/en/ => example.ru
example.ru/en/info/ => example.ru/info/
example.ru/en/catalog/ => example.ru/catalog/
```

I wrote the following regular expression:

```
(.+)\/(?<a2>\w\w)\/(.+)
```

and the following rule for Nginx:

```
location / {
  rewrite ^(.+)\/(?<a2>\w\w)\/(.+)$ $1 last;
}
```

but i get 404 error. How to fix this error so that the rewrite works correctly?

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/(?<a2>\w\w)(/.*)$ $2 last;`